# Approach to selecting a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

I am using Couchbase in a node app. Every time I insert a document, I am using a random UUID.
It inserts fine and I could retrieve data based on this id.

But in reality, I actually want to search by a key called url in the document. To be able to get or update or delete a document.

I could possibly add the url as the id I suppose but that is not what I see in any database concepts. Ids are not urls

or any unique names. They are typically random numbers or incremental numbers.

How could I approach this so that I can use a random UUID as id but be able to search by url?

Cos lets say the id was 56475-asdf-7856, I am not going to know this value to search for right.

Whereas if the id was https://www.example.com I know about this url and searching for it would give me what I want.

Is it a good idea making the url the id.

This is in a node app using Couchbase.

```
databaseRouter.put('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
  updateDocument(req)
    .then(({ document, error }) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(404).send(error);
      }
      res.json(document);
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error));
});

export const updateDocument = async (req) => {
  try {
    const result = await collection.get(req.params.id); // Feels like id should be the way to do this, but doesn't make sense cos I won't know the id beforehand.
    document.url = req.body.url || document.url;
    await collection.replace(req.params.id, document);
    return { document };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};
```

Comment: _"Is it a good idea making the url the id?"_ Couchbase document IDs can be no longer than 250 bytes. If the URLs are guaranteed to be shorter than this, then yes, it's fine to use an URL as a document ID. If the URLs can be longer, perhaps you could use a fast non-cryptographic hash of the URL as the document ID, and store info for multiple URLs in the same document.  If you need to store long URLs and want to store only one per document, consider using the query service with a secondary index on the url field, as padeso suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's okay to use URLs as IDs, especially if that's the primary way you're going to lookup documents, and you don't need to change the URL later. Yes, often times IDs are numbers or UUIDs, but there is no reason you have to be restricted to this.

However, another approach you can take is to use a SQL query (SQL++, technically, since this is a JSON database).

Something like:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM mybucket.myscope.mydocuments d
WHERE d.url = 'http://example.com/foo/baz/bar'
```

You'll also need an index with that, something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_url ON mybucket.myscope.mydocuments (url)
```

I'd recommend checking out the docs for writing a SQL++ query (sometimes still known as "N1QL") with Node.js: https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/current/howtos/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html

Here's the first example in the docs:

```
async function queryPlaceholders() {
  const query = `
  SELECT airportname, city FROM \`travel-sample\`.inventory.airport
  WHERE city=$1
  `;
  const options = { parameters: ['San Jose'] }

  try {
    let result = await cluster.query(query, options)
    console.log("Result:", result)
    return result
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Query failed: ', error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hash the url attribute (Using sha-1) of your document and use the hash result instead of the uuid of document.

```
{
"url":"www.google.com",
"otherAttr":"Some Value",
}
meta.id()=`2LmfaLIItUU7ORywxsPWqYJPPDo=`


{
"url":"www.yahoo.com",
"otherAttr":"Some Value",
}
meta.id()=`okmivkemZi3lnnpr4B1Xc2z/d0g=`
```

In my experience, I prefer not using n1ql and query engine because they have a lot of cost and complexity (Using N1QL is simple but not effective).